# How to create a task in Jira in Jenkins when an assembly crashes?

Tags: windows, jenkins, server, jira

If I get an error -> then create a Jira task -> $ {Date_time} _ $ {Build_number} _ $ {Status}?

What should I use? if you have any manual please share

Comment: You can access the [jira api](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/) within your Jenkinsfile if the job fails.

Comment: You can check out the [JIRA Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps/) for easily interacting with Jira via Jenkins.